# Eclipse RCP application is not setting the ERRORLEVEL upon System.exit()

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, errorlevel

When trying to invoke an Eclipse RCP application from a bat script, If the Eclipse terminates abnormally, then we are exiting the RCP application as `System.exit(10)`. And when I try to do echo `%ERRORLEVEL%` from script, then it is displaying the 0 instead of 10.

Whereas if I do the same thing with an normal Java Application (say with help of a JAR file), then it is logging as 10.

Any idea on why Eclipse RCP refuses to set the `ERRORLEVEL`?

Comment: Are there any wrapper-scripts that might be swallowing the `ERRORLEVEL` by running something after the RCP exits?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your relevant source code for running this application and getting its error level.

Comment: You aren't supposed to exit with error level an RCP application using System.exit(), but rather by using return value of IApplication.start(). What kind of problem makes you want to shut down using System.exit()?

Comment: @McMonster : Thanks for your prompt response !!, 
My bat script invokes the RCP application within itself. If any error is observed in due course of my RCP execution, then we are flagging in the form of Error code ( say 5, 6 etc.., for various purposes ) and the calling bat script should be aware of this exit value. If I try to log the ERRORLEVEL like echo %ERRORLEVEL%, then the script always prints as 0. 

NOTE : If I call a NORMAL JAVA APPLICATION through script, then the behavior is fine. i.e.., whatever ERRORLEVEL that was set though the JAVA APPLICATION the calling script displys the same

Comment: @Kenster : Any idea on my previous comment ??

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of providing exit code is by propagating it to your implementation of IApplication.start(). It should be returned as your desired error code boxed into Integer.

Comment: McMonster :   Ohh... thanks for your answer. Can you support your above answer with the help of some illustration so that I can be sure on what I do .

Comment: It depends on how your application works, basically where you use System.exit() now you have to return the value or pass it in any other way back to where your application starts (IApplication.start()). Can't be any more specific without seeing the code.

Comment: I think even with this the Eclipse native launcher code only supports exit codes of 0 and the two restart codes. Everything else is treated as 0 if I read the source correctly (http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/features/org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature/library/eclipse.c)

Comment: public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
  
  return new Integer(10);
I tried like giving this and observed that I got an excpetion stating as follows :

Java was started but returned exit code = 10

and thereafter if I do echo %ERRORLEVEL%, I'm always getting 0

Comment: @greg-449 : Thanks for your response..  It means that it is not possible to set the ERRORLEVEL from within an Eclipse RCP application ??

Comment: @McMonster : Kindly provide your feedback on my code which I've pasted in one of my previous comments.  I am getting a Exception dialog if I do return a Integer value inside the start() method.

Comment: @McMonster : I need to set the ERRORLEVEL from within my RCP application, If  this is achieved then I will be very much thankful to YOU.

Comment: If I do the same System,exit() for a normal JAVA APPLICATION, then the echo %ERRORLEVEL% works fine for me

Comment: @greg-449 : Thank you Greg for your information "I think even with this the Eclipse native launcher code only supports exit codes of 0 and the two restart codes. Everything else is treated as 0". The link was really helpful

Comment: @greg-449: Any workaround exists for setting the errorlevel from within an RCP application ?  Any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested by @McMonster, returning a Boxed Integer from IApplication start() method works fine. Previously I'd tried from Command prompt and I wondered that it always returned a Default '0' for me. Whereas if I run the same though BAT script, then it works fine.

Really Heartfelt Thanks to McMonster and Stack Overflow !!